# Do these commands look malicious?

Tags: security

Just found these commands in my shell history. I don't remember typing them and I don't know what they do. Well, I know what `more` and `netstat` do but I can't parse the others.

Do they look legit, or should I worry?

```
more /etc/passwd
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$' | cut -d: -f1
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
netstat
find /etc /var -mtime -2
du -h / | grep '[0-9\.]\+G'^C
```

My best guess is that someone is hunting through the passwd file - I don't see any new users being added - but I'm not sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these are harmful in themselves, but some may provide information that could be used in a later attack...or that is merely indulging someone's harmless curiosity.

`more /etc/passwd` views the password file.

The `cut ...` and the `awk` are displaying a list of users with 4-digit UIDs or UIDs >= 1000 respectively.

`netstat` displays the open network connections and unix domain sockets.

The `find ...` is looking for files in /etc and /var that are less than 2 days old.

The `du ...` is looking for directories containing more than 1GB of data.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me parse them a bit more easily :)